# NuGet Popup not showing when compiled to exe

Tags: c#, .net, build, nuget, exe

I'm using the Microsoft Toolkit for Windows 10 Notifications. When I debug the App in VS2019 it works and a notification in windows is displayed. But when I build the app nothing happens after running it in windows. Any suggestions?

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;

namespace Popup
{
    class Program
    {
       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Requires Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications NuGet package version 7.0 or greater
            new ToastContentBuilder()
                .AddArgument("action", "viewConversation")
                .AddArgument("conversationId", 9813)
                .AddText("Guten Morgen lieber Mitarbeiter:innen")
                .AddText("Schau dir gerne unsere Missionen, Visionen und Werte an")
    // Inline image
    // Text box for replying
    .AddInputTextBox("tbReply", placeHolderContent: "Gerne kannst du uns deiner Änderungswünsche zukommen lassen")

    // Buttons
    .AddButton(new ToastButton()
        .SetContent("Reply")
        .AddArgument("action", "reply")
        .SetBackgroundActivation())

    .AddButton(new ToastButton()
        .SetContent("Like")
        .AddArgument("action", "like")
        .SetBackgroundActivation())

    .AddButton(new ToastButton()
        .SetContent("View")
        .AddArgument("action", "viewImage")
        )
        .AddInlineImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\Jan.Hohnroth\Desktop\883-360x202.jpg"))
                .Show(); // Not seeing the Show() method? Make sure you have version 7.0, and if you're using .NET 5, your TFM must be net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0 or greater
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your application lives long enough to display this notification? Is there a blocking call in you main method to make your application stay alive and not quit immediately ?